# Import Data from Text File into Master File (changing target directories)- Excel

Tags: vba, excel, targeting

I know that this post is going to seem very similar to many other posts to those who understand it. I have learned C++ and C#, both only well enough to do minor work, and I just cannot understand VBA well enough to make this macro happen.

I have just under 100 files that need to be imported to a master file. I cannot modify the source files but the master file needs only select columns.

This macro works almost perfectly I just need the ability to select new file paths for each instance of the macro being used. I have found many posts that seem to use something like this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/231cbfc5-95ad-4673-a20c-f87355c6bc5e/prompt-user-for-file-name-to-import-as-fixed-width-text-file?forum=exceldev

in order to first make a filepath into a variable and then pass it to the ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add command. I might just be missing something but there are a lot of variables between all of the examples that I just don't understand. It seems like the msdn page for vba is much less intuitive than those for C#. Either that or I am simply unable to understand them having not taken the babysteps that I need.

Using the macro tool I made the large majority of the code below. About an hour of working allowed me to replace the hardcoded cell with the active cell.

```
Sub InputDataFromTextFile()
'
' InputDataFromTextFile Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;E:\Dropbox\College 2016-2017\Research\Buffered Solutions\pH10\With PDADMAC\30.CSV" _
        , Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .Name = "30"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any and all help that could be given. Thank you all so much for your time regardless.

Comment: The example you cite seems pretty straightforward.  If you haven't, you should also read the MSDN article on the [Application.GetOpenFilename Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx).  Write it as a separate macro and fiddle with it to see how it works.  What specific problem are you running into with it.

Comment: The code referenced tires to select an open table when I use it. I don't really need this as my code written by the macromaker just opens a file at a target. I just need to make it so the target is selected by the user rather than hardcoded. The issue I'm having is that the variable he uses to re-direct the target to a selected one "FileName" is written into so many code sections that I can't determine how to just get out what I need to. I tried for about another hour just now and most of last night.

Comment: Is this question resolved? Do note: you can answer your own question. Also, do you really want a dialog pop-up file picker for each of the just under 100 files? Consider looping through a directory with user selecting a folder picker only once.

Comment: @Parfait alright I am now at a point where the looping is going to be needed. Should I continue on this post or move to another?

Answer (score 0):

So immediately after posting, I hadn't figured it out in the comments I tried something and got it to work. Here is the code as it stands.

Sub InputDataFromTextFile()

```
Dim Filt As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim FileName As Variant

' Set up list of file filters
    Filt = "All Files (*.*),*.*"

' Display Text Files by default
    FilterIndex = 1

' Set the dialog box caption
    Title = "Select a File to Import"

' Get the file name
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
        FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
        Title:=Title)

' Exit if dialog box is canceled
    If FileName = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

'
' InputDataFromTextFile Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FileName, _
        Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .Name = "30"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

One of my largest issues was honestly that once excel was restarted the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that I had hotkeyed to the command reverted to making a table. I couldn't figure out where it was coming from! Thank you for your help. This saves me a great deal of time.

While the comment made by Parfait about cycling through the files and having them auto import is the next step and a very obviously desired trait in the code, it seems like a lot for me right now. I'm already saving upwards of an hour per mastersheet which is just amazing. Thank you all so much again.